# Crystal Reports 2008: field shows as blank even when data is returned from the database?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, crystal-reports-2008

### Issue

- I have a report in CR 2008 that I inherited from someone else
- A sub-report in the report pulls its data from a database view
- A field exists, "TRANSCBFLAG" in the view -- it's a string with values of "Y", "N", or "D"
- The view has these values
- The report displays every other value, but not this one field.

### Attempted Resolutions

- **Suppression attribute?** -- No, it's unchecked
- **Field type issue?** -- No, it's a string
- **Font and background?** -- No, it's black font / white background
- **Suppression / formatting formulas?** -- no formulas on display or suppression in subreports or report
- **Space constraints?** -- stretched the field out below all other fields -- still shows as blank
- **Check to make sure Crystal can see the data** -- right-clicked field, select "Browse Field Data", and it came back with the three potential values. So, it can see them in the DB at least, and potentially even in the fields itself.
- **Just a local Crystal Issue?** -- No; I uploaded the report to Business Objects XI for a test and all fields still display except that one.

### Question

Where in the process could I be going wrong? It shows when I run the view directly from the database, and every other field shows perfectly in Crystal the first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a more correct answer, but in a pinch, removing the view from my report (thus removing all fields), adding the view again, and redoing all fields caused the field to display correctly. Not sure how or why.

A further explanation would be appreciated, but for now, that's all I've got.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128659/how-do-i-point-crystal-reports-at-a-new-database #1 from Accepted answer has worked for me with similar situations to this one

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you did 'Verify Database' but if not that's the first thing I would have tried.

And just a piece of advice... always, always, always run your reports off of a command you write yourself instead of using Crystal's GUI to let you select tables/views/procs.  This allows you to make pretty much any kind of change to the query you want and even completely change the source from where your data is coming without wiping all your report controls away.  If the modified query has the same field names it will always work seemlessly and if not it will give you a chance to redirect which fields are supposed to come from where.  Otherwise... you will have to recreate everything as you just experienced.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on a new report I'd created and finally found that the issue was in one of the parameters I used in my command SQL - it had double }} at the end.  Eliminating one of the }s allowed the query to return data.

That said, go over the SQL in your database expert with a fine toothed comb, and you'll likely find the issue!