# Can you update a data table, without losing your columns in your report in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a Crystal Report that contains numerous fields and functions that all reference one SQL Server data view.  Recently, I've had to make a copy of the underlying SQL data view and make a few modifications. I need to use my new data view as my data source within my Crystal Report.

My problem is that I need to keep the original data view, without changing it's name, but I need my Crystal Report to reference the new data view.

Is there an easy way for me to update my report's data source without having to update all of my columns and formulas?  Otherwise, I'm starting from scratch and might as well create a new report, which I'd prefer not to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. I haven't used CR in a while, but I used to do that frequently. There's actually a built-in option to change your data source and remap any fields it can't find in the new data source.

Check out #1 of Todd Watson's answer:
[How do I point Crystal Reports at a new database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128659/how-do-i-point-crystal-reports-at-a-new-database)

Answer (score 7):

Go to Field Explorer -> Right click on Database fields -> Go to Set Datasource location -> In lower section (Replace with) -> Go to My Connections -> Right click on New Dataset (go to Refresh).