# Change the database source for Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports, report, rdlc

I am working with some old crystal reports that were part of a vb6 project, I am not that well versed with reports and due to time constraints I am running short of resources to invest

All I want to do is incorporate these reports into the new WPF application that I am creating

The database that it pulled info from is a little bit different from the database I created, design wise, the data (migrated from access to mysql) is the same

Should I just change the source in those reports, or should I create new reports and copy the sql (some have sql and some just have selected fields) from those reports preferably in the latest version of Crystal Reports or some other reporting app like RDLC

Comment: right now your source and denstination of dataSource of Crystal report are same

Comment: check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128659/how-do-i-point-crystal-reports-at-a-new-database, https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/en/1215396